# Chain IF conditions and Execute first one. In C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, chain

I am trying to do the following:

```
MyObject.If(x => x.ID == 10, new MyAction("ID10")).If(x => x.Value < 20, new MyAction("Value20")).DoSomethingWithMyAction();
```

MyObject is an object with a few properties which I need to check ...

DoSomethingWithMyAction() is a MyAction extension that does something with the MyAction of the first condition that fails.

If could be something like:

```
public static If<T>(this T myobject, Func<T, Boolean> predicate, MyAction action) where T : MyObject {

  if (predicate(myobject)
    // Return ??? >> Move to Next If
  else
    // Return action

} // If
```

Then DoSomethingWithMyAction() would simply be a MyAction extension.

My problems are:
1 - How to chain the IFs;
2 - How to make DoSomethingWithMyAction() use the MyAction of the first IF to fail.

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: With all due respect, what you are attempting to do is not idiomatic, it's bordering on unmaintainable.  An if/else block is going to be far easier to maintain than this.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I'd misunderstood your question, and haven't got time to revisit my code right now. But it's *something* like this:

You probably need to construct some sort of type representing the chain itself. Something like:

```
public class ChainedExecution<T>
{
    private readonly T target;
    private readonly ChainedExecution<T> previous;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> predicate;
    private readonly Action<T> action;

    private ChainedExecution(T target, ChainedExecution<T> previous,
                             Func<T, bool> predicate, Action<T> action)
    {
        this.target = target;
        this.previous = previous;
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public ChainedExecution<T> Or(Func<T, bool> newPredicate, Action<T> newAction)
    {
        return new ChainedExecution<T>(target, this, newPredicate, newAction);
    }

    public bool Execute()
    {
        if (previous != null && previous.Execute())
        {
            // An earlier action has handled it.
            return true;
        }

        if (predicate(target))
        {
            action(target);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static ChainedExecution<T> Start(T target, Func<T, bool> predicate, 
                                            Action<T> action)
    {
        return new ChainedExecution<T>(target, null, predicate, action);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public static class ChainedExecution
{
    public static ChainedExecution<T> If<T>(this T target,
                                            Func<T, bool> predicate, 
                                            Action<T> action)
    {
        return ChainedExecution<T>.Start(target, predicate, action);
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```
foo.If(x => x.Value < 20, x => Console.WriteLine("Bang! Too low"))
   .Or(x => x.Name == null, x => Console.WriteLine("Null name"))
   .Execute();
```

You'll need to change the `Action<T>` to a `MyAction`, and make `Execute` return the "value from the predicate which failed" or something like that... anyway, that's the general gist.